# Load renamed assembly and create instance

Tags: c#, sqlite, reflection, .net-assembly, invoke

I'm developing software which uses the mixmode System.Data.SQLite.dll. I need to deliver 4 of them (x86 and x64 for .net 2.0 and 4.0) in one folder. That is why I renamed it like

> System.Data.SQLite.x64.dll

Based on platform I will load one of them and create the `SQLiteConnection` using reflection

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"d:\sqlite-netFx20-binary-bundle-x64-2005-1.0.92.0\System.Data.SQLite.x64.dll");
Type t = assembly.GetExportedTypes()[8];
object sqliteCon = Activator.CreateInstance(t, @"Data Source=d:\nwind.db;Version=3;");
```

The last line throws an exception

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Unable to load DLL 'System.Data.SQLite.dll': The specified module
>   could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I do not reference the SQLite.dll in my project.
I have no problem running this code if the dll has it's original name.

Calling CreateInstance on the `assembly` object and getting the constructor from the type and invoking it are throwing the same exception:

```
//ConstructorInfo ctor = t.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
//object instance = ctor.Invoke(@"Data Source=d:\nwind.db;Version=3;");

//object ass = assembly.CreateInstance("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection", false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[] { @"Data Source=d:\nwind.db;Version=3;" }, null, null);
```

**Question:** why does this happen and how can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO it would be simpler to create an installer that would supply the proper DLL for the system rather than shipping all 4 and renaming them.

Comment: @DStanley not in my case as my software is a class library for software developer so I have to deliver all of them

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because you have renamed the .DLL. Unless you want to change some variables in the mete data you will have to rename the library in some way.

I had the problem before and this is the solution I used:

```
        string tempFile = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "System.Data.SQLite.dll");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\System.Data.SQLite_x64.dll"));
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(tempFile);
        Type t = assembly.GetExportedTypes()[8];
        object sqliteCon = Activator.CreateInstance(t, @"Data Source=d:\nwind.db;Version=3;");
```

It will create a copy of the file into the temporary directory on your computer and it will rename it back to the original name.

You shouldn't forget to delete the file whenever you shutdown your application.

--EDIT:

The method I used above isn't really the right method for your project, since you only have to determine once what library you need. Thus I would rename the right library the first time the program loads, this way you won't have to create a temporary file each time the user fires up your program:

```
        string myPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string originalName = "System.Data.SQLite.dll";

        // If we haven't already renamed the right library
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", myPath, originalName)))
        {
            foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(myPath))
            {
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                if (fileName.StartsWith("System.Data.SQLite."))
                {
                    // !! Do your platform checks here !!
                    // ..

                    // Copy the file with its original name
                    System.IO.File.Move(file, file.Replace(fileName, "System.Data.SQLite.dll"));
                    // Delete old file (not necessary)
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                }
            }
        }

        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", myPath, originalName));
```

Comment: +1 I like your edit, but I forgot to mention, that my software is a class library for developers. It is possible that developer will reference one of those DLLs in his project which also uses my library so file renaming is not my favourite solution

Comment: Thanks. I understand that in your case you wouldn't go with file renaming. You can loop through the assembly its referenced libraries and check if one of those references is your library and if not, you can always drop your own library on disk (or, if already there, rename it).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is that you are probably changing the dll's file name after compiling it. The DLL's original filename attribute is stored inside meta data of the dll along its compilation. This is why it not really a good idea to rename dlls but to recompile them using the new name.

Recompile your DLL 4 times for all your use cases and the problem would go away.

Comment: I've just tried to do that, but still getting the same exception. Now I really don't know why. If you have some spare time, could you please try it? http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.92.0/sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.92.0.zip . I left only SQLite.Interop.2013, SQLite.Interop.Static.2013, System.Data.SQLite.2013 and System.Data.SQLite.Module.2013 . I've modified the Target name in SQLite.Interop.Static.2013, and the dll has the new name now. Thanks

Comment: @VladL That's strange. As there should be no reference to the old name anywhere. Unless there is one the DLL itself. Unfortanately I'm not able to do that at the moment. But I suggest you use Fuslogvw.exe to dump the Fusion activity(dll resolution). It will help you see which module is trying to load that DLL and where it is looking for it.